# JS bug: highlight words, insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex, highlight, case-insensitive, no-framework

It easily highlight words, framework free, case insensitive, even on html tagged code.

Could help improve that Pure JavaScript code?

Works, almost perfectly.

```
(document.body).realcar("word high");
```

Bug only happens when: user search for sequential words.

The second word is replaced to other word in the sentence, that came after " " (last space of the textual fragment). Because it is not replaced to the searched second word.

Works perfectly to search for: "light nos", on that case:
`Highlight <strong>nossa!</strong>`

Bugged function:

```
    HTMLElement.prototype.realcar = function(word) { var el = this;
const wordss = word.trim().sanitiza().split(" ").filter(word1 => word1.length > 2);
  const expr = new RegExp(wordss.join('|'), 'ig'); 
  let expr00 = expr; 
  const RegExpUNICO=wordss; 
  const nodes = Array.from(el.childNodes); 

  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    const node = nodes[i];

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      const nodeValue = node.nodeValue;  let matches = [];
      while ((match = expr.exec((nodeValue).sanitiza())) !== null) {
        //console.log("++"+match); 
        matches.push(match[0]);
      const palavrar = nodeValue.substring(match.index, match.index+match[0].length);
    RegExpUNICO.push(palavrar); 
        }
      expr00 = RegExpUNICO.join('|');
      let expr0 = new RegExp(expr00, 'ig');
      console.log("**"+expr00);
       
      
      
      if (matches) {
        const parts = nodeValue.split(expr0);

        for (let n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) {
          if (n) {
            const xx = document.createElement("hightx");
            xx.style.border = '1px solid blue';
            xx.style.backgroundColor = '#ffea80'; 
            const startIndex = nodeValue.indexOf(parts[n - 1]) + parts[n - 1].length;
            const palavra = node.nodeValue.substr(startIndex, matches[n - 1].length);
            xx.appendChild(document.createTextNode(palavra));
            el.insertBefore(xx, node);
          }

          if (parts[n]) {
            el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(parts[n]), node);
          }
        }

        el.removeChild(node);
      }
    } else {
      node.realcar(word);
    }
  } 
}
```

Try the code here: https://jsbin.com/vegihit/edit?js,console,output
Please help debug and fix it!

Comment: Side note: proper indentation of code improves the readability. I mean, look at `keyup_high` in your link: what a mess that is.

Comment: You might want to refrain from adding methods to built-in prototypes and make them normal functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is in this line:

```
const startIndex = nodeValue.indexOf(parts[n - 1]) + parts[n - 1].length;
```

This assumes that `parts[n - 1]` will only occur once in `nodeValue`, but this is not guaranteed. For instance, `parts[n - 1]` could be a single space, and have an occurrence earlier in the string, and then the wrong word will be picked up.

Another, less problematic, issue is that `if (matches)` will always be true, since even an empty array is a truthy value. This should be `if (matches.length)`.

To solve the first problem there are several possible solutions: your aim is to know which is the next, adjacent subtring to extract from `nodeValue`. You can achieve this by including the separators in the output of `nodeValue.split(expr0)`. You can do that by having a *capture group* in your regex. This will mean your loop will iterate both the not-matched substrings as well as the matched substrings -- covering the whole string without omissions.

Here is the correction of the relevant code:

```
if (matches.length) { // Must test the .length
    // Move the creation of `expr0` here :
    // Create a capture group by adding parentheses: 
    const expr00 = "(" + RegExpUNICO.join('|') + ")";
    const expr0 = new RegExp(expr00, 'ig');
    const parts = nodeValue.split(expr0);
    
    for (let n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) {
        const textNode = document.createTextNode(parts[n]);
        if (n % 2) { // A matched term; always at odd index because of capture group
            const xx = document.createElement("hightx");
            xx.style.border = '1px solid blue';
            xx.style.backgroundColor = '#ffea80'; 
            // No more need to determine an index or length: we have the exact substring
            xx.appendChild(textNode);
            el.insertBefore(xx, node);
        } else if (parts[n]) { // A (nonempty) substring that is not part of a match
            el.insertBefore(textNode, node);
        }
    }
    el.removeChild(node);
}
```

Comment: That is great! I hope that framework free code could be useful in many cases. Thanks you for your help